# Is there a way to specify meta keywords and descriptions with Drupal?

Tags: seo, drupal, meta-keywords, meta-description

I would like to be able to specify some meta keywords and meta descriptions for some of my pages in our Drupal (version 6) site. However, there does not appear to be a way to do that within Drupal (at least out of the box). I've seen some references to some Drupal modules which might allow you to do this, but it doesn't look like they've been updated in a long time. Any suggestions?

As a correlary, if meta keywords and meta descriptions really aren't worth bothering with any more, is there a way I can tell Hubspot to stop reminding me to add them? :)

Comment: As you can see in Erion's reply, you'll get better answers when you tell us which Drupal version you are using.

Comment: Good point. We're using Drupal 6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm using NodeWords: http://drupal.org/project/nodewords

(but it does not run on Drupal 7, so your success will depend on what version of Drupal you are using for your site)

Regarding the updates, the dev version was updated just yesterday, and the released version is not that old as to make me doubt its usefulness or support status.

Meta descriptions will help Google show a description for your page under the search result instead of some random snippet of text taken from the page. It may be worth it just for that :)

Comment: Nodewords will not be supported on Drupal 7, because it will be replaced with http://drupal.org/project/metatags. There may be an upgrade path, so it's not sure (yet) if you can start using Nodewords now and upgrade to Metatags later.